# edit mode on gridview showing record to be edited with empty values

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, gridview

I have a gridview with records from a sql table. I have set up the webpage in a 3 tier architecture such that when I choose to edit a particular record from the gridview it gives me a formview populated with the details of the record I selected in the gridview.When I click the update linkbutton  after changing some  details on the formview, the gridview is displayed with a blank record of the selected row.I need this row on the gridview to have the data.

Please help.

My code behind.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        BindGrid();
        fvProfiles.Visible = false;
    }
}

protected void BindGrid()
{
    gvProfiles.DataSource = new UserBO().GetAllUsers();
    gvProfiles.DataBind();
}

 protected void ShowGrid()
{
    fvProfiles.Visible = false;
    gvProfiles.Visible = true;
    btnAdd.Visible = true;
}

protected void HideGrid()
{
    fvProfiles.Visible = true;
    gvProfiles.Visible = false;
    btnAdd.Visible = false;
}

protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HideGrid();
    fvProfiles.ChangeMode(FormViewMode.Insert);
}
protected void InsertButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ShowGrid();
}
protected void InsertCancelButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ShowGrid();
}



protected void gvProfiles_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName =="Edit")
    {
        gvProfiles.Visible = false;
        fvProfiles.Visible = true;
        btnAdd.Visible = false;
        fvProfiles.ChangeMode(FormViewMode.Edit);
        odsProfiles.SelectParameters["UserId"].DefaultValue = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
        odsProfiles.DataBind();
    }
    if (e.CommandName == "LogicalDelete")
    {
        int i = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
        //call the userBO method to logically delete the record.
        //new UserBO().DeleteUser(i);
    }
    if (e.CommandName == "Delete")
    {
        int i = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
        //call the userBO method to delete the record.
        new UserBO().DeleteUser(i);
    }
}
protected void gvProfiles_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    BindGrid();
}
protected void UpdateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ShowGrid();
}
protected void UpdateCancelButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ShowGrid();
}
protected void gvProfiles_RowUpdated(object sender, GridViewUpdatedEventArgs e)
{
    BindGrid();
}
}
```

`odsprofiles` is an objectdatasource.

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing the gv rows before databinding it like so:

```
protected void BindGrid()
{
    gvProfiles.DataSource = new UserBO().GetAllUsers();
    gvProfiles.Rows.Clear();
    gvProfiles.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for responding but gvProfiles.Rows collecton doesn't contain a definition for Clear and no extension method Clear() can be found.